# Why Bigquery is giving me result in two rows where I am expecting to have one row

Tags: google-bigquery, full-outer-join

I am using full outer join to check which table, which is corresponding to a monthly data, has this SKU. The SKU in the example is 560715760. 
In this particular instance the SKU is present all the months from Jan to Sep except for August. 
I am expecting the output of this query to be of one row with SKU column corresponding to August (H.SKU SKU_H) to be null.
But in reality it is giving me two rows, one with all the months null but Sep one not null and the other row contains all columns with the SKU except for the tables corresponding to August and September. Please help understand the full outer join functionality in the case.

I have observed that when August month (where the SKU is not present) is removed from the query it is giving me one row in the output. I am suspecting it has something to do with the null value coming from August month table.

```
SELECT A.SKU SKU_A,B.SKU SKU_B,C.SKU SKU_C,D.SKU SKU_D,E.SKU SKU_E,F.SKU SKU_F,G.SKU SKU_G,H.SKU SKU_H,I.SKU SKU_I
  FROM  (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH1_JAN` WHERE SKU = 560715760) A --NOT NULL
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH2_FEB` WHERE SKU = 560715760) B ON (A.SKU = B.SKU) --NOT NULL
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH3_MAR` WHERE SKU = 560715760) C ON (A.SKU = C.SKU AND B.SKU = C.SKU) --NOT NULL
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH4_APR` WHERE SKU = 560715760) D ON (A.SKU = D.SKU AND B.SKU = D.SKU AND C.SKU = D.SKU)  --NOT NULL
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH5_MAY` WHERE SKU = 560715760) E ON (A.SKU = E.SKU AND B.SKU = E.SKU AND C.SKU = E.SKU AND D.SKU = E.SKU) --NOT NULL
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH6_JUN` WHERE SKU = 560715760) F ON (A.SKU = F.SKU AND B.SKU = F.SKU AND C.SKU = F.SKU AND D.SKU = F.SKU AND E.SKU = F.SKU)  --NOT NULL
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH7_JUL` WHERE SKU = 560715760) G ON (A.SKU = G.SKU AND B.SKU = G.SKU AND C.SKU = G.SKU AND D.SKU = G.SKU AND E.SKU = G.SKU AND F.SKU = G.SKU)  --NOT NULL
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH8_AUG` WHERE SKU = 560715760) H ON (A.SKU = H.SKU AND B.SKU = H.SKU AND C.SKU = H.SKU AND D.SKU = H.SKU AND E.SKU = H.SKU AND F.SKU = H.SKU AND G.SKU = H.SKU)  --NULL
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH9_SEP` WHERE SKU = 560715760) I ON (A.SKU = I.SKU AND B.SKU = I.SKU AND C.SKU = I.SKU AND D.SKU = I.SKU AND E.SKU = I.SKU AND F.SKU = I.SKU AND G.SKU = I.SKU AND H.SKU = I.SKU) --NOT NULL
```

Expected Result:
SKU_A,SKU_B,SKU_C,SKU_D,SKU_E,SKU_F,SKU_G,SKU_H,SKU_I
560715760,560715760,560715760,560715760,560715760,560715760,560715760,,560715760

Actual Result:
SKU_A,SKU_B,SKU_C,SKU_D,SKU_E,SKU_F,SKU_G,SKU_H,SKU_I
     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,560715760
560715760,560715760,560715760,560715760,560715760,560715760,560715760,,

Comment: I reckon joining condition is causing the issue, please help me to point out where exactly I need to modify

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to see which of the given months have seen your desired SKU. Given your table structure, you can achieve it with a much simpler wildcard approach in BigQuery (using its special `_TABLE_SUFFIX` meta-column):

```
select 
   cast(_TABLE_SUFFIX as string) as month, 
   if(sum(if(SKU = 560715760, 1, 0)) > 0, true, false) as sku_present
from `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.MTH*` 
group by 1
order by 1
```

Hope it helps.